# Receiving continuous data stream with sockets in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to write a client application, which connects to a server on a specified port and receives data.

I found [this fine example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but my problem is that the server is sending me data all the time (not closing the conection), and so ReceiveCallback never ends, because client.EndReceive(ar) never returns 0.

So, my WinForm is freezing during receiving data.

The idea is to monitor all the incoming data and make some callbacks on certain occasions.

I'm new to C#, could you point me to right direction? Multithreading?

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "continuous" instead of "infinite". You would want to handle the receive in a worker thread.

Comment: Yes, you need to have a separate thread that can handle waiting to receive and processing the data.  It seems you already pointed yourself in the right direction.  There is a *lot* of information on the subject out there.

Comment: The callback for BeginReceive() doesn't occur on the main UI thread, so when you call EndReceive() you aren't there either.  Therefore receiving continuous data isn't the problem.  If you're immediately Invoke()ing back to the main UI thread, however, then I could see the message queue getting flooded.  One possibility would be to place the data into some kind of global buffer, then only periodically update your UI or data from a Timer() in the Form.  Can you give more details about the data and what you're doing with it?

Comment: Show some code. In particular, show the call to `BeginReceive`, and show your receive callback function. I suspect the problem is somewhere other than where you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have two threads: one for the user interface, and another that reads from the "infinite socket". The infinite thread loops forever reading from the socket in appropriately sized chunks, perhaps doing some preprocessing. It then uses Control.Invoke() to call a method on the UI thread, passing the chunk to it in a parameter. Make sure the chunks are small enough that the UI thread can process them without locking up, say in 0.1 secs.